# Is a P-shaped path a Jordan's Curve?

Tags: curves

> Is a path that has shape "$P$", a Jordan's curve?
>
> If no, state why?

Anyway, what i'm trying to say is a path, that has no intersection (i'm not sure), but its initial and end point didn't meet at a point.

That path can be described as a letter "$P$".

Answer (score 0):

Consider the question: is "P" homeomorphic to $S^1$? Try to consider the connected components you get by removing a point from the two spaces.
Alternatively, if you don't want to use topology, consider possible parametrizations of "P", let's say a continuous map from $[0,1]$ to $\mathbb R^2$ such that $f(0)=f(1)$ and injective in $[0,1)$: in order to be injective you need f(1) to be the point of "auto-intersection" of $P$. Can you now conclude?

Comment: I've not learned topology anyway, Is that mean, Letter P is homeomorphic with Letter S? So it's not a Jordan's Curve then?

Comment: $S^1$ is a circle. Or in other words a letter $O$

Comment: Ok, last question. So it's a Jordan's Curve right?

Comment: If you agree with the definition I give in my answer, P is not a Jordan curve.